# App does not start when using SharedPrefernces

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm coding my own private Android application with Android Studio. I want to store data with SharedPreferences, but when I use it, my app does not start. Can anyone help me?

Code of main MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ACCOUNT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        //unimportant code
    }
    
}
```

If I delete these 2 lines starting with SharedPreferences, my app starts, but now it doesn't.

Comment: move your these 2 lines of code after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 1):

> move your these 2 lines of code after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` –
> [M DEV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16765223/m-dev)

Thanks mate this solved my problem :D